# Why does C# infer this type as dynamic?

Tags: c#, type-inference

I have the following code.

```
public static void GuessTheType()
{
    dynamic hasValue = true;
    dynamic value = "true";

    var whatami1 = hasValue ? (string)value : null;
    var whatami2 = hasValue ? bool.Parse(value) : true;
    var whatami3 = hasValue ? (bool)bool.Parse(value) : true;
}
```

The type inferred by the compiler for `whatami1` is `string`.
The type inferred by the compiler for `whatami2` is `dynamic`.
The type inferred by the compiler for `whatami3` is `bool`.

Why is the second type not `bool`?

Comment: That's... weird. I hope you don't mind, I edited your question to add a third example.

Comment: Since `value` is `dynamic`, C# can not chose `bool.Parse` overload at compile time, thus compile type of `bool.Parse(value)` is `dynamic`.

Comment: @PetSerAl But even `var whatami = bool.Parse(value.ToString());` results in `whatami` being `dynamic`. Or is this just a cascading effect?

Comment: @john `value.ToString()` is `dynamic` because we can not know return type of `ToString()` method on `dynamic` type.

Comment: Even though there is only one `bool.Parse` overload?

Comment: @Blorgbeard What if runtime assembly actually have more overloads of `bool.Parse` then reference assembly provided at compile time? You ask for dynamic binding, so you get one.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on PetSerAl's comment, which explains *why* it's treated as dynamic, you can avoid having your call to `bool.Parse` treated as dynamic by casting the value to a string:

```
var whatami2 = hasValue ? bool.Parse((string)value) : true;
```

Comment: Or cast the result of the parse as a bool.

Comment: I was focusing on avoiding any dynamic calls at all, but good point!

Comment: @CameronMacFarland I am guessing `(bool)bool.Parse(value)` has more overhead than `bool.Parse((string)value)`, because it has to find a `bool.Parse` that matches at runtime (you can compare the generated IL in LINQPad)

Comment: @Slai : I can see only `public static Boolean Parse(string value);` method for `Boolean` struct. No other overload !

Comment: @AkashKC As per PetSerAl's comment on the original question: "What if runtime assembly actually have more overloads of bool.Parse then reference assembly provided at compile time? You ask for dynamic binding, so you get one"

Comment: @RichardSzalay : Still I don't understand it completely. As `var` is inferring `dyanmic` type in compile time, shouldn't it reference the same assembly which has been referenced like in my case `// C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.Runtime.dll`

Comment: @AkashKC And what if you're reference .NET Standard, but the runtime implementation provides overloads?

Answer (score 1):

Casting is our assertion (to the compiler) that an object really is something else - for example:

```
var whatami1 = hasValue ? (string)value : null;
var whatami3 = hasValue ? (bool)bool.Parse(value) : true;
```

Finally, parsing is interpreting a value from a form with no intrinsic relationship - i.e. there is no *direct* relationship between a dynamic ( i.e. value) and var (i.e. whatami2), but we can parse:

```
var whatami2 = hasValue ? bool.Parse(value) : true;
```